# Angular 8 Universal - Как отдать код ошибки 404

Tags: typescript, angular, ssr

Подскажите пожалуйста, каким образом отдать http код 404 на странице 404, при помощи SSR Angular Universal. Код с 7 версии Angular не работает, выдает массу бесконечных ошибок.Код приведен ниже.

```
//Код компонента страницы 404 (notfound.component.ts)

import {Component, Inject, OnInit, Optional, PLATFORM_ID} from '@angular/core';
import {RESPONSE} from '@nguniversal/express-engine/tokens';
import {isPlatformServer} from '@angular/common';
import { Global } from '../core/global'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-not-found',
  templateUrl: './not-found.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./not-found.component.css']
})
export class NotFoundComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    public global: Global,
    @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object,
    @Optional() @Inject(RESPONSE) private response,
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    if (isPlatformServer(this.platformId)) {
      this.response.status(404);
    }
  }

}
```

```
//Часть кода в файле server.ts

import {REQUEST, RESPONSE} from '@nguniversal/express-engine/tokens';

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index', { 
    req,
    providers: [
      {
        provide: RESPONSE,
        useValue: res
      }
    ]
   });
});
```

P.s Если есть другие идеи и предложения, как реализовать отдачу кода, буду рад предложениям)

Comment: создай воспроизводимый пример и покажи всем, что ты уже сделал, чтобы кто-то мог скачать твой пример себе локально и поиграться с ним

Comment: чувак, ну выложи какой-то код на гитхаб :) у тебя такая задача что это нужно потрогать руками, а не гадать на кофейной гуще. Я уверен, что никто не захочет поднимать у себя сам universal ради твоего вопроса, другое дело если б код уже был готовый

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Единственный найденный (**рабочий**) способ реализации отдачи кода 404 для **Angular 8** - Universal, это добавление кода в файл конфигурации веб сервера **Nginx**

```
error_page 404 /404.html;
location = /404 {
       return 404;
}
```

Данный метод работает для страницы 404 при прямом переходе на нее, но не при переадресации на нее.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/patrickmichalina/fusebox-angular-universal-starter/blob/master/src/client/app/shared/services/server-response.service.ts

Полагаю, вы можете использовать приведенный выше код.

(наше в сл. ветке обсуждения - https://github.com/DSpace/dspace-angular/issues/91#issuecomment-318547118)

Comment: Не работает. Судя по отсутствию документации по Angular 8 - Universal, Google перерабатывают SSR Universal или они решили оставить его таким каким он сейчас является. Ранее для Universal был выделен отдельный сайт - поддомен universal.angular.io, теперь осталась одна единственная (малоинформативная) статья (https://angular.io/guide/universal)

Answer (score 0):

В server.ts нужно передавать res, а не только req.

У меня работает так:

```js
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  // было: res.render('index', { req });
  res.render('index', { req, res });
});
```

без всяких провайдеров